Importing functions from several modules into one and then exporting all of them at once
I have many subfolders and files in ../foo that export many functions. I would like to collect all of them in one module and export them all together to be used myModule.ts. The following certainly works but is tedious (we are taking 200+ functions), is there a better way?
// collection.ts
import { a, b, c } from '../foo/bar';
import { d, e, f } from '../foo/baz';
import { x, y, z } from '../foo/qux';

export { a, b, c, d, e, f, x, y, z };

// myModule.ts
import * as FUNCTIONS_LOOKUP_TABLE from './collection';

const myFunc = (index) => FUNCTIONS_LOOKUP_TABLE[index].call(...)


I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but I offer the suggestion that you read through what can be done with a package.json file to define how export paths map to source files.

Thanks, I added some more context above to what I am trying to do.

try import * as bar from '../foo/bar'; and so on and const all = { ...bar, ...baz, ...qux } and export { all } now from myModule FUNCTIONS_LOOKUP_TABLE['all'] should give all functions and can be accessed by key

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel: Just use export * from 'foo/…'; for all of those foo modules, no need to write out their names (or even repeat them)

@cmgchess No, don't build an object. Keep using named exports.

@Bergi Thanks! It didn't work line that in one file for the entire folder, but worked when I specified it on a file-by-file basis export * from 'foo/bar', export * from 'foo/baz', export * from foo/quz, etc. Still saved me a lot of lines of code, thanks again.

@savreline Yes, that's what I meant. You still need to list all the modules from which you want to export, you just don't need to list all the individual exports.
